# Django set cookie using middleware fails on first page load

Tags: django

There's a cookie I need to be present from the start of the site so I set it using middleware like this

```
#https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware

def set_lang_cookie(get_response):

    def middleware(request):
        response = get_response(request)

        if not request.COOKIES.get('lang'):
            response.set_cookie('lang', 'en')

        return response

    return middleware
```

it works but the first time loading a page for example after closing the browser and opening it again or using incognito it throws an error that the cookie doesn't exist because this is how I pipe it into a template filter

```
{{ pg.title|translate:request.COOKIES.lang }}
```

is there a work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
def set_lang_cookie(get_response):

    def middleware(request):
        language = request.COOKIES.get('lang', None)
        if language:
            request.lang = language
            response = get_response(request)
        else:
            request.lang = 'en'
            response = get_response(request)
            response.set_cookie('lang', 'en')

        return response

    return middleware
```

And use it in template:

```
{{ pg.title|translate:request.lang }}
```

**FYI:** I would recommend using [**`django translation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/) instead of your implementation.

Comment: I prefer this implementation because it's simpler, I would use it if it proves it can translate text inside html tags, for now though I want to see if my implementation can do that also.